# How to write in 1 line with the Html.Helper between 2 text in the same label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Having the following code with HtmlHelper in .cshtml:

```
<div class="row form-group col-lg-12" >
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ScheduleType, "Montly")
   <label>
       On the 
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DayOfMonth, Model.DayOfMonthList, new { @class = "form-control select2"}) 
       of the month
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to print those 2 HtmlHelper in 1 line (the RadioButton will enable/disable the dropdown)

Right now, the result I'm having is causing to display the radio button as the image below. I want to print everything in one line. Is there a way to print all of these in the same line just by changing the razor, html or view, or it needs to be manage by something else? (css, jquery,etc)

[image]

Comment: from your picture, it looks like your drop down list is style as a block level element, you need to change it to something like `display: inline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to add a wrapper class div with inline-block around your `DropDownListFor` and text block. It prevents them filling up the whole line, thus rendering them next to eachother, like in the example below.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>
    On the 
    <div class="wrapper">
        <select id="dayOfMonth">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select> 
   </div>
   of the month
</label>
```

Comment: thx, that helped. I thougth if I did it in the outer `<div class="col-lg-6">` would make that happen, but apparently needed that inner `<div>`